# Time value that should be 24:00 displays as 0:00

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a weird problem in Excel 2010.

Cell `C8` is formatted as **Time** and has formula `=E48/24`. 
Cell `C9` is formatted as **Time** and has formula `=24-C8`. 
Cell `E48` is formatted as **General**.

This works perfectly if I put `15.5` in cell `E48`;
it returns `15:30` and `8:30` in `C8` and `C9`, respectively.

My issue is when `E48` is empty, or explicitly contains 0,
both `C8` and `C9` read as zero. 
I want them to evaluate to `0:00` and `24:00`, respectively.

The purpose is for `C8` to show the up time for the device within a 24 hour period and `C9` to show the down time for that same period.

Expected result:

```
  C   | D |  E      ||     C   | D |    E 
13:30 |   |         ||    0:00 |   |
 8:30 |   |         ||   24:00 |   |
      |   | 15.5    ||         |   | (empty)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm really confused reading your question:( Adding screenshot or data in tabular formatmight help to explain it.

Comment: This question needs its title changing, but I can't understand what the issue is well enough to do it @Scott

Comment: @LondonRob:  You’re right; that original title didn’t make much sense.  I’ve rewritten it.

Comment: @Scott Is the issue in your new title *really* at the heart of the OP's question? Maybe it is. I haven't looked into it.

Answer (score 1):

Format your `C8` and `C9` as Custom format `[h]:mm`

Then, put on `C9` this formula `=1-C8` instead of `=24-C8`

Putting 24 on your `C9` will break your formula if there is a value on `E48`

Comment: Works perfectly       And i appreciate the explanation on why it broke  Thank you very much

Comment: +1  for presenting the correct information, even though you didn't explain it.

Comment: @Scott what I can explain so this answer can be more thorough?

Comment: Just look at my answer.  (And don't bother updating yours, at this point, unless you can see some aspect that I missed.)

Comment: @Scott Ah yes, that explains my suspicion why my `C9` evaluates to `560:something` when I used 24. Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

What you have now is working for the wrong reason. 
Obviously, `E48` is a number of hours,
so `C8`, which contains `=E48/24`, is a number of days. 
If `E48` is between 0 and 24, then `C8` will be between 0 and 1,
expressing a fraction of a day. 
This corresponds to the way Excel’s date/time storage works —
a date/time is stored as the number of days
(including a fraction of a day, as necessary) since midnight, January 1, 1900. 
That’s why `C8` is correctly displaying
as the number of hours and minutes
corresponding to the number of hours in `E48`.

But, if `E48` is between 0 and 24, and `C8` is between 0 and 1,
then `24-C8` is a number between 23.0 and 24.0. 
Specifically, if (as in your example) `E48` is 15.5,
then `C8` is 0.645833333 and `C9` is 23.35416667. 
Since `C8` expresses a number of days,
the `24` is interpreted as a number of days. 
If you change the format of `C8` and `C9`
to a custom format of `d "days and" h:mm`,
you will see that, for `E48` = 15.5,
`C8` will be `0 days and 15:30` and `C9` will be `23 days and 8:30`.

So, two things:

- Since `C8` is a number of days, you want `C9` to be `=1-C8` —
  computing the rest of the day, and not looking at a 24 day period.
- In an Excel cell display format for a date/time value,
  the `h` (and `hh`), `mm`, `ss`, and `AM/PM` tokens
  look only at the fractional part of the value —
  i.e., the fraction of a day, which corresponds to a *time of day*. 
  (Note the way the 23.35416667 value is displayed as `23 days and 8:30`;
  the `8:30` corresponds to the 0.35416667 fraction.)

  A blank `E48`, of course, is interpreted as a value of 0,
  and will cause `C8` to evaluate to 0. 
  With `C9` set to `=1-C8`, it will evaluate to 1. 
  If you still have `C9` formatted as `d "days and" h:mm`,
  you will see that it displays as `1 days and 0:00`,
  which, of course, is equivalent to 24 hours. 
  To get it to ***display*** as `24:00`,
  you need to use **`[h]`** in the format instead of just plain `h`;
  i.e., use a format of **`[h]:mm`** instead of just plain `h:mm`. 
  The `[h]` token looks at the *entire* value in the cell
  (not just the fractional part) and will display hours ≥24.

Comment: Worth pointing out in Military/UTC time, 24:00 doesn't exist, it's actually 00:00 to avoid this exact problem.  00:00:01 to 23:59:59 is the time frame of a valid day.

Comment: @Ramhound:  I’m not sure that is worth pointing out in this context.   This question is not about 24:00 as a designation for the midnight that comes one second after 23:59:59, it is about a *measurement* of a *duration* (period of time), expressed to the granularity of minutes.   As in, if you work 7:30 (7½ hours) a day for five days, you have worked a 37:30- (37½ hour)-week.

Comment: tbh, the title needs changing again, because @Ramhound 's thought reflected mine too, & it took a lot of reading to figure out that wasn't the intent of the question.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Question titles are meant to give the reader a general idea of what the question is about, and to facilitate searching.  They are not meant to embody the entirety of the question; that’s what the question body is for.  If people are misunderstanding what a question is about because they’re reading the title and not the body, I’m not really concerned about that.  Is this the clearest question in the history of [SU]?  No, but that’s not my responsibility either.  If you believe you can do better, go ahead — you’ve got editing privileges.